# Cancel Stripe Subscriptions not working when a user cancelled a Subscriptions from PaidMemebership Pro wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments

Cancel Stripe Subscriptions not working when a user cancelled a Subscriptions from PaidMemebership Pro wordpress plugin,

When user cancelled Subscriptions from wordpress account using PaidMemebership plugin then it's cancelled from wordpress account but it's status still shows as active on stripe panel.

Please guide me where should i focus to fix this on Priority, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow please read the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to improve your question with code examples to help the community help you better

Comment: You would, unfortunately, need to work with the Plugin developer to resolve this.  It sounds like a programming bug.